# Using keyup on input with attribute name

Tags: jquery, html, addeventlistener, keyup

Im doing application and I have a problem with "addEventListener" and "keyup".
So, i have this html code:

```html
<input class="width50" type="number" name="metraz" value="<?php echo $metraz; ?>" />
```

And JS code:

```html
document.getElementsByName("metraz")[0].addEventListener("keyup",validate_numb("metraz"));
```

If i write in html "onkeyup="validate_numb('nameoffield')" - will be fine, but if i trying code I pasted before - then isn't working. Anybody have sugestions where i have an error?

EDIT. 
That is all the code (something isn't working here because function validate_numb calls me document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value - undefined after i used for loop and array)

```html
   var items = [
        "metraz",
        "cena_dodatkowa_ogrzewanie"
    ];
    for(i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        console.log(items[i]);
       document.getElementsByName(items[i])[0].addEventListener("keyup", function(){
       validate_numb(items[i]) 
        }); 
    }
    

    function validate_numb(name){//argumentem jest nazwa pola
        var input = document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value;
        var parsed_input = parseInt(input);//wartosc pola zamieniana na liczbe całkowitą
        if(isNaN(parsed_input) || parsed_input<0 || input!=parsed_input){
            document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value="";
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert a callback function, not an expression.

In JS, when you add listeners or define future events, you're supposed to give a reference to the function that will be used whenever the event occurs. If you immediately invoke the function and let the result be saved in the listener, you won't have what to do next time the event happens.

Change:

```
document.getElementsByName("metraz")[0].addEventListener("keyup",validate_numb("metraz"));
```

To:

```
document.getElementsByName("metraz")[0].addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    validate_numb("metraz")
});
```

Comment: Could you look at it? :)

Comment: Sorry, I mislead you by mistake - the loop wouldn't work as-is because the scope of the `i` is not lexically defined. Here's a [workaround](https://jsfiddle.net/d30atfrh/1/) and you can [read more](http://tobyho.com/2011/11/02/callbacks-in-loops/) about the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `addEventListener` needs to be a function.

You are calling `validate_numb` **immediately** and passing its return value (which, presumably, is not a function).

The quick and dirty solution to this would be:

```
...addEventListener("keyup",function () { validate_numb("metraz") });
```

The better solution would be to rewrite the function so that the `name` wasn't needed at all.

```
function validate_numb(event) {
    var element_to_test = this;
    // etc etc
}

...addEventListener("keyup", validate_numb);
```